# AppSettings fallback/default value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, appsettings, namevaluecollection, fallbackvalue

ASP.NET

For each appSetting I use, I want to specify a value that will be returned if the specified key isn't found in the appSettings.  I was about to create a class to manage this, but I'm thinking this functionality is probably already in the .NET Framework somewhere?

Is there a NameValueCollection/Hash/etc-type class in .NET that will let me specify a key and a fallback/default value -- and return either the key's value, or the specified value?

If there is, I could put the appSettings into an object of that type before calling into it (from various places).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything built into .NET which provides the functionality you're looking for.

You could create a class based on `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` that provides an overload of `TryGetValue` with an additional argument for a default value, e.g.:

```
public class MyAppSettings<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public void TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value, TValue defaultValue)
    {
        if (!this.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            value = defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

You could probably get away with `string`s instead of keeping in generic.

There's also [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx) from the Silverlight and WPF world if those are options.

Of course, the simplest way is something like this with a `NameValueCollection`:

```
string value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(appSettings[key]) 
    ? defaultValue 
    : appSettings[key];
```

`key` can be `null` on the string indexer. But I understand it's a pain to do that in multiple places.

Comment: I provided an extension method to do this that includes TypeConverstion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34053423/375727.

Obviously not for the OP, as this post is 5 years old, but the future googlers like me who didn't find the answer here.

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET's ConfigurationManager provides that functionality. You can bind your configuration section (retrieved with `.GetSection("MySection")`) to an object with either `.Get<MySectionType>()` or `.Bind(mySectionTypeInstance)`. This also has the benefit, that it does conversion for you (see integers in the example).

#### Example (NET 6)

appsettings.json

```json
{
  "MySection": {
    "DefinedString": "yay, I'm defined",
    "DefinedInteger": 1337
  }
}
```

MySection.cs

```cs
// could also be a struct or readonly struct
public class MySectionType
{
  public string DefinedString { get; init; } = "default string";
  public int DefinedInteger { get; init; } = -1;
  public string OtherString { get; init; } = "default string";
  public int OtherInteger { get; init; } = -1;

  public override string ToString() => 
    $"defined string :   \"{DefinedString}\"\n" +
    $"defined integer:   {DefinedInteger}\n" +
    $"undefined string : \"{OtherString}\"\n" +
    $"undefined integer: {OtherInteger}";
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
ConfigurationManager configuration = GetYourConfigurationManagerHere();

// either
var mySection = configuration.GetSection("MySection").Get<MySectionType>();

// or
var mySection = new MySectionType();
configuration.GetSection("MySection").Bind(mySection);

Console.WriteLine(mySection);

// output:
// defined string :   "yay, I'm defined"
// defined integer:   1337
// undefined string : "default string"
// undefined integer: -1
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I do.

```
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyValue"] ?? "SomeDefault")
```

For Boolean and other non-string types...

```
bool.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyBoolean"] ?? "false")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom configuration section and provide default values using the DefaultValue attribute.  Instructions for that are available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx).

Comment: Another good answer that shows how poorly I've asked my question.  I may need to specify different fallback/default values depending on the caller (and/or values which are determined only at runtime).  I shouldn't have mentioned appSettings, as I really need, simply, a NameValueCollection-type object that lets me specify the value to return if the key isn't found.

Answer (score 1):

You can build logic around ConfigurationManager to get a typed way to retrieve your app setting value. Using here TypeDescriptor to convert value.

```
/// <summary>
/// Utility methods for ConfigurationManager
/// </summary>
public static class ConfigurationManagerWrapper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use this extension method to get a strongly typed app setting from the configuration file.
    /// Returns app setting in configuration file if key found and tries to convert the value to a specified type. In case this fails, the fallback value
    /// or if NOT specified - default value - of the app setting is returned
    /// </summary>
    public static T GetAppsetting<T>(string appsettingKey, T fallback = default(T))
    {
        string val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[appsettingKey] ?? "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
        {
            try
            {
                Type typeDefault = typeof(T);
                var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
                return converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)) ? (T)converter.ConvertFrom(val) : fallback;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(err); //Swallow exception
                return fallback;
            }
        }
        return fallback;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the machine.config under C:\%WIN%\Microsoft.NET will do this.  Add keys to that file as your default values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154.aspx

Comment: Machine.config would give me a fallback value, but I wouldn't be able to specify it in code?  Is that right?  I'm looking for something that lets me specify, in the code, the value that should be returned if the appSettings doesn't have the key I specify.  I mention appSettings, but this question is as much about any NameValueCollection/Hash as it is about appSettings (or *.config) specifically.