# ConfigurationManager & Static Class

Tags: c#, .net, static

I would like to use `ConfigurationManager` to access some string values from a *static* class. However, I need to handle specifically the absence of a value or the presence of empty values. Right now I was using type initializers, like

```
private static readonly string someStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["abc"];
```

to do the job. However, if a string with key "abc" doesn't exist in `App.config` the execution will happilly continue with a `null` reference in place of `someStr`. What is, then, the best way to validate this value on initialization? A static constructor in which I initialize the value and then check for validity? I heard static constructors are to be avoided and replaced by type initializers when possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using something like this:

```
public static readonly string someStr  = 
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["abc"] ?? "default value";
```

Or to handle empty string:

```
public static readonly string someStr = 
           !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["abc"]) ? 
                             ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["abc"] : "default value";
```

Answer (score 5):

This just came up in a code review. The answers provided are great for strings. But they don't work for an int or a double, etc... Today, I needed to do this for a retry count and it needs to be an int.

So here is an answer for those who want Type conversion included.

Use this extension method:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Rhyous.Config.Extensions
{
    public static class NameValueCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static T Get<T>(this NameValueCollection collection, string key, T defaultValue)
        {
            var value = collection[key];
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) || !converter.IsValid(value))
            {
                return defaultValue;
            }

            return (T)(converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(value));
        }
    }
}
```

I also have unit tests for it, which you can find here: http://www.rhyous.com/2015/12/02/how-to-easily-access-a-web-config-appsettings-value-with-a-type-and-a-default-value

Hope that helps the next guy.

Comment: This is now in my Rhyous.Collections NuGet package and you can see the source on GitHub: https://github.com/rhyous/Collections/blob/master/src/Rhyous.Collections/Extensions/NameValueCollectionExtensions.cs

Comment: Would it make sense to constraint T as convertible, i.e., `where T : IConvertible`? I don't think we're ever going to try to get the key value with a struct or class default value.

Comment: You might be correct. I am not sure why I didn't do this.

Answer (score 3):

static constructors are fine, the great thing about them is that they are *guaranteed* by the runtime to be executed once and once only - the first time the class is used in any circumstance.

You could alternatively use the coalesce operator (`??`) to set a default value:

```
private static readonly string someStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["abc"] ?? "some default value";
```