# Keep more of the url for requests SwaggerWcf

Tags: c#, wcf, config, swagger, swagger-wcf

My WCF service is locally hosted like this:
`localhost/service.svc`
On the server it's hosted like this:
`servername/extra/service.svc`
When making a request SwaggerWcf uses the base path and adds the configered elements:
`localhost/user/parameter`
But it should be:
`localhost/extra/user/parameter`
So I need WCF to not just use the hostname, but also a little more of the url.
I could add it to the SwaggerWcf configuration, which is `user` and could be `extra/user`. But then it won't work locally anymore.

I've tried adding a Config class that could read configuration attributes statically:

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace Project
{
    public static class Config
    {
        public static readonly string SwaggerWcfRequestPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SwaggerWcf.RequestPath"] ?? "/user";
    }
}
```

But when I try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189509/configurationmanager-static-class):

```
[SwaggerWcf(Config.SwaggerWcfRequestPath)]
public class Service: IService
```

It still produces the same error:

```
Error   46  An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.
```

How can this be done dynamically? Then it can be different for different environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do it
But I'll take a look into this later today

Probably the best way is allowing to override it using Web.config

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="swaggerwcf" type="SwaggerWcf.Configuration.SwaggerWcfSection, SwaggerWcf"/>
  </configSections>
  <swaggerwcf>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Host" value="www.msampleservice.com"/>
      <setting name="BasePath" value="/myserviceapi"/>
    </settings>
  </swaggerwcf>
```

Comment: Can the service path be configured in the Web.config? That would totally solve my problem.

Comment: I didn't need the host setting, adding the basepath works. I still need the global.asax file.